# WordPress - WooCommerce - show contact form when there is no Price

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, contact-form-7

I'm building a virtual shop - WooCommerce - and I need a unique solution, I'd be happy to get a link to code or possibly a plugin.
I have products with price, and have products without price.
On the product page itself, I would like to show contact form, only to products without a price. a contact form (CF7) had prepared in advance.
How and where do I put the code reviewer, and how can I put the content of the field - which has the shortcode of CF7? And where I can add the field with shortcode?
I am somewhat at a loss.

Comment: where exactly do you want to put the cf7?

Comment: Hello,

I want to put the contact form inside the single-product, after the meta before the sharing.

Answer (score 1):

You can try these steps to get desired output :

**STEP 1**

First you need to override `content-product.php` template file by copying file inside `YOUR_THEME\woocommrece\content-product.php`

**STEP 2**

Open the file `YOUR_THEME\woocommrece\content-product.php` and use this code before end of `li` tag

```
if( empty($product->price) ){
   echo do_shortcode('[YOUR CF7 SHORTCODE]');
}
```

Please Note I'm using woocommerce `2.4.12`

Comment: Hello,

thanks for the reply, I want to put the contact form inside the single-product, after the meta before the sharing. and - I wana take the shortcode from a field inside the wordpress (adding a new field to the woocommerce price section). is it possible?